# Página de ajuda sobre privilégio ficou desatualizada

Tags: bug, status-pronto, sinalização, central-de-ajuda

Uma [mudança recente no sistema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861/167534) deixou a [página de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) sobre o privilégio "acesso às ferramentas de moderação" desatualizada: ela continua falando sobre a fila de sinalizações, que deixou de existir.

---

#### Update 2014-08-31

Estranho, eu achei que o Gabe havia corrigido isso há um tempão. Mais alguém tem a mesma impressão? Será que o problema voltou, ou nunca deixou de existir?

Comment: Ver também: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1207/como-analisar-sinalizacoes-na-pagina-de-moderacao